# how to modify metadata of a doc document

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j, poi-hssf

I'm looking to modify certain tags (like comments, keywords, etc) of a .DOC file. I've been able to do this for DOCX using docx4j but I haven't been able to find anything that lets me change the tags for a .DOC format.

Is there a way to programmatically change the content of certain tags in a .DOC file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache POI will quite happily let you read and edit the metadata of supported documents. For the older OLE2 formats (.doc, .xls etc), you'll want to use [HPSF](http://poi.apache.org/hpsf/how-to.html), likely via [POIDocument](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIDocument.html). For the OOXML formats (.docx, .xlsx etc) use [POIXMLDocument](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.html) and [POIXMLProperties](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLProperties.html)

To modify the OLE2 properties, you can either follow the [detailed instructions and code in the HPSF documentation](http://poi.apache.org/hpsf/how-to.html#sec3), or on newer version of POI you can short cut quite a bit of that with [HPSFPropertiesOnlyDocument](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hpsf/HPSFPropertiesOnlyDocument.html), eg

```
NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File("test.doc"));
HPSFPropertiesOnlyDocument doc = new HPSFPropertiesOnlyDocument(fs);

SummaryInformation si = doc.getSummaryInformation();
if (si == null) doc.createInformationProperties();

si.setAuthor("StackOverflow");
si.setTitle("Properties Demo!");

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("changed.doc");
doc.write(out);
out.close();
```

Comment: What poi version is `HPSFPropertiesOnlyDocument` in? I'm using 3.10beta1 from maven but I don't find it in there.

Comment: Try a recent nightly build, or wait a couple more days for 3.10 beta 2 (Tim's working on the release candidate at the moment!)